# excel forumal round off the values

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In excel formula I am in need to round off the values. So my query is how I can set the function if 4th decimal value greater than or equal to 5 means I need to round off the 3rd value. This is what my query.

Comment: guys help me to get the answer

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+round

Answer (score 1):

Set the cell A1 to 1.23456789

Set A2 to "=ROUND(A1,3)"

A2's value shows as "1.235"

The round function takes as the first parameter, the number you wish to round off.  The second parameter is the number of decimal places to keep before the rounded slot.   So, you want the decision to be made off the 4th decimal, set the second parameter to 3.

**EDIT** (due to comment) :

So, check the 4th decimal place and if >= 5 round at 3rd place, else don't touch value at all?

If the number is A.BCDEFGHIJ... then if E >= 5, return A.BCD or D+1 if we round up, or if E<5 return full number A.BCDEFGHIJ...

```
=IF((MOD(A1*10000,10)>=5),ROUND(A1,3),A1)
```

So, if A1 = 1.23456789, then the answer is 1.235 but if A1 = 1.23446789, then the answer is 1.23446789

**How it works :**
I take A1 and multiply by 10000 to make the 4th digit to the left of the decimal, then modulus with 10, to remove all other digits and then check that digit against a value of 5.   If >=5, we round off at the 3rd decimal place, otherwise, we return the full number.

Comment: thanks boss.but my condition is if 4th decimal value >=5 then round of the 3rd decimal value else no need to roundoff the value

Comment: How is that formula then?